# How to use two different EditorTemplates for a base ViewModel and an derived ViewModel in the same View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a lot of ViewModels that derive from a base ViewModel.

Is it possible to display an EditorTemplate for the part of the derived ViewModel that comes from the base ViewModel, and a different template for the derived part, all in the same View? If yes, how is it done?

Base ViewModel:

```
public class ShowQuestionViewModel
    {
        public int Question_ID { get; set; }
        public String Question_Wording { get; set; }
        public String Question_Type { get; set; }
        public String Question_Number { get; set; }
        public Boolean Visible { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsAnswered { get; set; }

    }
```

Derived ViewModel:

```
public class ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel : ShowQuestionViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<MatrixRows, List<MatrixColumns>> columnrow;
        public List<MatrixColumns> columns;
        public List<MatrixRows> rows;

        public ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel()
        {
            columns = new List<MatrixColumns>();
            rows = new List<MatrixRows>();
            columnrow = new Dictionary<MatrixRows, List<MatrixColumns>>();
        }
    }

    public class MatrixColumns
    {
        public int Column_ID { get; set; }
        public int Column_Number { get; set; }
        public String Column_Description { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsAnswer { get; set; }
    }

    public class MatrixRows
    {
        public int Row_Id { get; set; }
        public String Row_Number { get; set; }
        public String Row_Description { get; set; }
    }
```

So, when i use EditorFor(x => ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel), i want to use a special editor for the properties that come from ShowQuestionViewModel.

Comment: Just create a custom editor template for `ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate editor template:

```
@model ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then define a custom editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel.cshtml` where you could customize all properties including those for the base type.

Comment: But is it possible to reuse the code for the base type when you do it this way?